# How do I set it up so that the below login method accepts input from 2 JTextfield boxes?

Tags: java, swing, jaas

The problem is that this is a JAAS login application.  The below method uses Java's Callback class and it's kinda bugging me out. Because it is wired in with the Callback class (among other things) the standard

```
       JTextfield username = Class.getText();
```

isn't working.  Your thoughts are welcome:

```
     public boolean login() throws LoginException {

   // prompt for a user name and password
   if (callbackHandler == null)
       throw new LoginException("Error: no CallbackHandler available " +
        "to garner authentication information from the user");

   Callback[] callbacks = new Callback[2];
   callbacks[0] = new NameCallback("user name: ");
   callbacks[1] = new PasswordCallback("password: ", false);

   try {
       callbackHandler.handle(callbacks);
       username = ((NameCallback)callbacks[0]).getName();            


       char[] tmpPassword = ((PasswordCallback)callbacks[1]).getPassword();            


       if (tmpPassword == null) {
       // treat a NULL password as an empty password
       tmpPassword = new char[0];
       }
       password = new char[tmpPassword.length];
       System.arraycopy(tmpPassword, 0,
        password, 0, tmpPassword.length);
       ((PasswordCallback)callbacks[1]).clearPassword();

   } catch (java.io.IOException ioe) {
    throw new LoginException(ioe.toString());
   } catch (UnsupportedCallbackException uce) {
    throw new LoginException("Error: " + uce.getCallback().toString() +
    " not available to garner authentication information " +
    "from the user");
   }

       . . .
```

Comment: Wouldn't the CallbackHandler contain the code that gets the input from the user, in this case, call the Swing code and then return only after the user is done entering the data?  Perhaps this is the code you should be showing and not the LoginModule code.  What problems are you having? What are you trying to do with this line? `JTextfield username = Class.getText();` as it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Hello Hovercraft Full Of Eels.  I wanted to issue you a heartfelt THANK YOU for your comment earlier today.  I pointed me in the right direction & let me know that I did not understand the whole callback process as good as I ought to.  So, hours later after a break and a glass of wine (or two :)   I ended up putting the JTextfield call statement in my Callback Handler!  And whoala!  It works. . . sweet!  Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Hovercraft Full Of Eels pointing me in the right direction, I was able to figure it out.  Below is the correct code in the my Callback handler (not my Login Module as I originally though above):

```
 public void handle(Callback[] callbacks)throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException 
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) 
     {
         if 
         {
             . . . .
         }
         else if (callbacks[i] instanceof NameCallback) 
         {

    // prompt the user for a username
    NameCallback nc = (NameCallback)callbacks[i];  
    System.err.print(nc.getPrompt());
    System.err.flush();
    nc.setName(Video_Game_Store.usrName.getText());

     } 
         else if (callbacks[i] instanceof PasswordCallback) 
         {

    // prompt the user for sensitive information
    PasswordCallback pc = (PasswordCallback)callbacks[i];
    System.err.print(pc.getPrompt());
    System.err.flush();         
            pc.setPassword(Video_Game_Store.psWord.getText().toCharArray());

     } 
         else 
         {
    throw new UnsupportedCallbackException
        (callbacks[i], "Unrecognized Callback");
     }
 }
 }
```